# Time stamp and JsonDate format conversion

Tags: c#, json, datetime, ravendb

In my MVC view, I am taking user input for date and passing that value to a controller action.

The date I am passing comes into the controller parameter with a timestamp. Later in the controller code, I am comparing that date parameter to a date value from the database. The database date value is in JSON Date format.

My questions two fold..

1. How to get just the date passed into the controller and not with time stamp. Or how can I convert that date format with time stamp into just `mm/dd/yyyy` format.
2. Once I do that, how can I compare two values. One date is in regular `mm/dd/yyyy` format and the other date (from database) is in JSON date format as `"/Date(1324414956395)/"`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why on Earth are you storing JSON formatted dates in your database instead of using a datetime column? I would recommend you rethinking your database design. Your question is not really related to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I am using RavenDB as my database. It has JSON format dates in its earlier versions.

Comment: I am not familiar with RavenDB but I strongly suspect that its .NET client driver has some DateTime conversion capabilities no matter how it stores the dates. I mean its ridiculous if you get the `"/Date(1324414956395)/"` string out of your database instead of a DateTime instance. I just cannot believe it. Anyway, my point stands: your question has nothing to do with asp.net-mvc. Please retag it with the data access specific technology you are using.

Comment: RavenDB does not have date formats like that any more. I just happen to use one of the earlier versions. Please let me know if you have any good suggestions on how to do this. Thank you. Also please see my question 1 also.. Json format is q2.

Comment: ZVenue, RavenDB doesn't save the json format anymore, but it can still ready it. Just query over the date time instance normally, it will figure things out for you

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method to do it:

```
        private static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
        {

            var original = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            return original.AddSeconds(timestamp);

        }
```

Comment: you pass in the 1324414956395 part of the string as a double

Comment: I want to convert mm/dd/yyyy to "/Date(1324414956395)/" format.. not the other way around.. the "timestamp" you are passing in my case is in the mm/dd/yyyy format. How do I do this in my case?

Comment: what if you tried (today - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds  Today would be the date your are converting from.  Then take out the . and add the /date() to the string.